# SUMX Multiple Filter Criteria + VARs

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've seen a couple posts that have helped push me along with the proper DAX structure. My background is SQL so I would have approached this with a over partition, however, I think I'm pretty close with my current code. EARLIER() didn't seem to allow me to select my desired variables, so I saw another post that said to declare the variables within the calculated measure.

However, I can resolve my "syntax for 'FILTER' is incorrect".

```
Factor2 = SUMX(Test_Table,
    VAR FiscalYear = Test_Table[FiscalYear]
    VAR Segment    = Test_Table[Segment]
    Var PerChange  = FILTER(Test_Table,Test_Table[FiscalYear]=FiscalYear && Test_Table[Segment]=Segment),Test_Table[PercentChange])

RETURN PerChange/[MaxYear]
```

I was also unable to figure out how to apply an if/then with logic like:

IF FiscalYear = MAX(Year), then Factor2 = 1,
ELSE: (run above code)

If this fairly simple to include, please advise, otherwise I can continue to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
Factor2 =
VAR FiscalYear = Test_Table[FiscalYear]
VAR Segment = Test_Table[Segment]
VAR PerChange =
    FILTER (
        Test_Table,
        Test_Table[FiscalYear] = FiscalYear
            && Test_Table[Segment] = Segment
    )
VAR Result =
    SUMX ( PerChange, Test_Table[PercentChange] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        IF ( FiscalYear = MAX ( Test_Table[Year] ), 1, DIVIDE ( Result, [MaxYear] ) )
    )
```

Your comment "What if we just were to try and find the PercentChange for max(FiscalYear) by segment/PercentChange Would that be eaiser?"
So I tried this one:

```
Factor3 =
VAR FiscalYear =
    MAX ( Test_Table[FiscalYear] ) -- VAR Segment = Test_Table[Segment]
VAR PerChange =
    FILTER (
        Test_Table,
        Test_Table[FiscalYear] = FiscalYear -- && Test_Table[Segment] = Segment
    )
VAR Result =
    SUMX ( PerChange, Test_Table[PercentChange] )
RETURN
    Result
```

Note: "--" sign preceding the statement means that line is converted to comments, and has no effect on DAX code.

Comment: I receive the errors "cannot find [FiscallYear]" and "cannot find [Segment]" on lines 2 & 3.

Comment: I think we maybe want to add a SUMX() between lines 1 & 2 ?

Comment: SUMX is not needed there. It is a column reference. We can maybe use aggregate functions(Min, Max, Count etc..) but we need to do it with a logic. For example MAX(Test_Table[Fiscal Year])

Comment: Now, I updated the code. please test it again.

Comment: Can you share your model view? you can paste it into your post as a screenshot.

Comment: Seems to yield results now, but they all show as 1, because we're only looking at max(FiscalYear) which is = FiscalYear (based on how we defined it)

Comment: because conditional if statement always evaluates to True, and sets Factor2 equal to 1 as in the condition.

Comment: Now I made some changes, and updated the code. you need to test it again.

Comment: Still showing as 1 for all FiscalYears, when the actual Test_Table[PercentChange] varies YoY. We should be seeing almost every FiscalYear not equal to 1, except for 2022 (which is the current [MaxYear]).

Comment: It's the IF() statement that's getting things hung up. When I add sumx() between lines 1 & 3, remove the selectedvalue() from both variables, and simply return Result/[MaxYear] it seems to work. Just need to solve for IF()

Comment: please paste the updated code into your post.

Comment: Current code updated above, missing IF() bit

Comment: what is [MaxYear]?  It is a column  in your table?

Comment: It is a measure = max(FiscalYear). In this case, 2022

Comment: Another update. Please test it.

Comment: I get the errors again with lines 2 & 3 and also 14 says "parameter is not the correct type", referring to 'Result'

Comment: I still try to find out what caused this. I updated the code again.

Comment: still need to solve for lines 2 & 3. What if we just were to try and find the PercentChange for max(FiscalYear) by segment/PercentChange

Would that be eaiser?

Comment: what you mean by segment/PercentChange? segment is a text field, PercentChange is decimal(numeric). The result returns division error.

Comment: I added Factor3 measure in response to your last comment. please check it.